# How do I prevent QGIS 1.8.0 changing my dbf table values when joining tables?

Tags: qgis

Im a newbie on GIS as well as QGIS. I have a table of data saved from Excel as dbf format. After dragging and dropping the file into QGIS and then opening the attribute table, all values less than 1 in my original table have been changed to 0. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks ike your data has been stored as integer values, instead of real that you wanted.

You can try importing as CSV, and create a CSVT file with the attribute table data types.

Comment: thanks Andre. Importing as CSV with a CSVT file solves this problem, but what if I have a very large table of data? It seems very long winded to have to produce a csvt file and I thought dbf was a quicker, easier option?

Comment: The dbf file should contain the data type in the first row. Look at some shapefile .dbf as example. See http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm for details. Not all data types are supported for shapefiles.